# Pass parameters to Windows Terminal?

Tags: command-line-arguments, windows-terminal

Currently I am using MinTTY for my Cygwin terminal needs. Lacking a tabbed interface, I am looking to move to "Windows Terminal", which is currently distributed as a Store app on Windows 10.

The Windows Terminal can be invoked as `wt.exe`, but this just opens a new window. What I want to achieve is to open

1. a new tab
2. in a specified directory
3. with a specified shell.

A use case would be for instance to open a new tab in the location of the current File Explorer window. For MinTTY and Cygwin's bash I have achieved this with the registry entry

```ini
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\kdb.CygwinBashHere]
@="Cygwin &bash here (mintty)"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\kdb.CygwinBashHere\command]
@="C:\\cygwin\\bin\\mintty C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash -lc \"cd '%V' || cd $(dirname '%V'); bash -i\""
```

I am essentially looking for an equivalent of the command `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty ARGS ...`.

I am using similar patterns from within AutoHotkey for starting `cmd.exe` and `mintty.exe` with bash in the directory of the currently opened document in various programs through Autohotkey.

I am aware, that Autohotkey can probably be used to achieve the behavior I want. However, a clear command line interface for the windows terminal would be the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment Windows Terminal doesn't support command line parameters. We need to wait until the below issues are closed

- [Spec for adding commandline arguments to wt.exe](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/3495)
- [Feature Request: wt.exe supports command line arguments (profile, command, directory, etc.)](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/607)

Comment: As of 2021-Jun 23 and before parts of these listed items are implemented in wt.exe